# MySQL SELECT only if doesn't match

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I'm trying to do a select from a table based on the value of a name field.

I want to only match certain criteria if a record is not based on the first, ie.

if the following matches:

```
WHERE name='version'
```

if so return that single row, if not, look for these too:

> WHERE name='v' OR name='e' OR name='r'
>   etc...

Is this possible in a single query?

Many thanks!

Comment: I think you probably want to use LIKE. But your question isn't very clear. You want to match if the field is equal to any of those single letters? Or if it contains those letters?

Comment: You're going to end up using either LIKE or REGEXP, depending on what your use-case exactly is... As @Cfreak said above, we'd need some clarifications in what exactly you try to achieve...

Comment: @Romain, no, not really, neither LIKE nor REGEXP can look further then a single row; therefore they can not help to implement logic that would determine if to select another resultset or not.

Comment: @Unreason: You're absolutely right... A third reading of the question gave me a different (better) understanding of the point...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ...
FROM ..
WHERE name = 'version'
UNION ALL
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT ...
      FROM ..
      WHERE name = 'version'
      ) AND name IN ('v', 'e', 'r', ...)
```

**EDIT:**
Not sure how to test if mysql would cache the results of the first query, but assuming you run the query in a new session:

```
SELECT @cached:=1, ...
FROM ..
WHERE name = 'version'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, ...
FROM ...
WHERE @cached IS NULL AND name IN ('v', 'e', 'r', ...)
```

should work

If in the same session you want to clear the `@cached` with

```
SELECT @cached:=1, ...
FROM .., (SELECT @cached:=0) x
WHERE name = 'version'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, ...
FROM ...
WHERE @cached = 0 AND name IN ('v', 'e', 'r', ...)
```

Comment: Thanks, that definitely works is that the most efficient way to achieve what I'm after then?

Comment: @user369190, there might be some tricks with server variables to avoid running the query twice, I'll test it... also not sure but mysql will probably cache the results of the first run of the query. @Andry M, read OP question - he wants rows with 'v', 'e', 'r' *only* if there are no rows where name is equal to 'version'

Answer (score 1):

```
select ...
from ..
where (name = 'version') or (name in ('v', 'e', 'r', ...))
```

Though, since you're basing the comparison on the same field, there's no difference between  the above version and

```
...
where (name in ('version', 'v', 'e', 'r', ...))
```